# how to remove generic content of matplotlib regardless of type plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've looked around for a while and found a number of clever ways to remove content from a plot.

e.g. lines = blah, del lines[0], line gone.

but this obviously doesn't work for histograms, or imshow for instance.

Is there a way to clear the plotting area (i.e. not using clf()) without having to regenerate the entire figure. This requires you to have no strict knowledge of what is currently plotted but still be able to remove it. I am developing an application which uses the same area for plotting and I want a generic way to remove the content for different types of graphs I want to display. Some lines, some scatter, some hist etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you can display on an `axes` is a subclass of `Artist` and have a member function `remove` [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove).  All of the plotting functions (should) return the `artist` (or list of `artists`) that they add to the axes. Ex:

```
ln, = ax.plot(...) # adds a line
img = ax.imshow( ) # adds an image
ln.remove()        # removes the line
img.remove()       # removes the image
```

You will have to re-draw the canvas (`plt.draw()` or `ax.figure.canvas.draw()`) before the changes are visible.

You can get a list of all the artists in a given `axes` with

```
artist_list = ax.get_children()
```

If you want to remove everything from an axis,

ax.cla()

Comment: That is good for a single set of points plotted, but if img = blah is in a loop - how do you remove the points previous plotted in the loop?self.displaypoints[0].remove() will only remove the most recently plotted, not all of the points.

Comment: @Griff You just have to hold on to the references (say in a list).

Comment: OK thanks, but how do I remove the children in one go? > artist_list = self.main.display.get_children() > artist_list.remove() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Griff see edit.  And you just have to iterate over the list elements.